# Toggle Button returns after restarting the application

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, togglebutton

I have recyclerView and I have like 5 cardView with toggle buttons on each of them so when i click on them they work perfectly lets say (on,off) but the problem is when i restart the application this toggle buttons that i decided to be on goes to be off i tried with sharedpereference but it didn't worked so here is my code can someone help and thanks

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyHolder>{

Context c;
String[] players;
String[] positions;
int[] images;





public MyAdapter(Context ctx,String[] players,String[] positions,int[] images)
{
    this.c=ctx;
    this.players=players;
    this.positions=positions;
    this.images=images;

}
@Override
public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.model,null);

    MyHolder holder=new MyHolder(v);
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = c.getSharedPreferences("com.example.xyz", MODE_PRIVATE);
    holder.fav.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean("NameOfThingToSave", true));
    return holder;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyHolder holder, final int position) {



    holder.nameTxt.setText(players[position]);
    holder.posTxt.setText(positions[position]);
    holder.img.setImageResource(images[position]);
    // holder.fav.setChecked(false);

  // holder.fav.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(c, R.drawable.star_off));
    holder.fav.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (holder.fav.isChecked())
            {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = c.getSharedPreferences("com.example.xyz", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putBoolean("NameOfThingToSave", true);
                editor.commit();
            }
            else
            {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = c.getSharedPreferences("com.example.xyz", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putBoolean("NameOfThingToSave", false);
                editor.commit();
            }
            if (isChecked)
                holder.fav.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(c,R.drawable.star_light));
            else
                holder.fav.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(c, R.drawable.star_off));
        }
    });


    holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View v, int pos) {

            Intent i=new Intent(c,DetailActivity.class);

            i.putExtra("Name",players[position]);
            i.putExtra("Position",positions[position]);
            i.putExtra("Image",images[position]);

            c.startActivity(i);

        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return players.length;
}
```

Comment: I dont see any `sharedpreferences`.

Comment: i deleted because it didn't worked

Comment: If you want to maintain the state for your application you have to use `database` or `sharedprefs`

Comment: check the sharedpreference

Answer (score 0):

Use this Shared Preference 
**For Set**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(Activity);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("KEY, true/false);
    editor.commit();
```

**For Get**

```
SharedPreferences prefs =PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    boolean check=prefs.getBoolean(fieldName, false);
```

Comment: how this going to help me to save my button state

Comment: When you check button than setCheck(true) and store in ArrayList<test> so when you back on your app than get ArrayList and set as you set   Also Shared Preference is help for me  Like  use this  public void saveBooleanPreference(Context context, String key, Boolean value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

Comment: still this doesn't do anything in onCreate in mainactivity or onCreate adapter
how the application will remember the state this is just for checking

Comment: use above sharedpreference it must help you

Comment: place my shared preference in another class and than use i have use this code already

Comment: MyHolder class MainActivity class ..?

Comment: didn't get what you want to tell

Comment: create another class in your package and place my code and use

Comment: so after adding your class and using set and get from it what about the sharedpreference  its giving me my saved click onCreateViewholder

Comment: use only Shared Preference for that

Comment: okay it is working but it not working with the position all yes or all no :S

Comment: 1 toggle button on every cardView or row

Comment: SnapShot of code--
                    getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();  // Here we get the position that we have set for the checkbox using setTag.
                    arrayList.get(getPosition).setSelection(buttonView.isChecked()); // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.
                    if (isChecked) {
                        checkBoxCounter++;
                    } else {
                        checkBoxCounter--;
                    }
                }
            });

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45979628/toggle-button-positions-in-recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

Can u share your shared prefs implementation so we can maybe correct it?

This code only shows how you present your data to UI but not saving check state.

You need to save check states somehow and load them when app started. There are few easy solutions.
So you need to make a list of object where each object contain your relevant data including check status and save that list in shared prefs or any other data storage. 
Or you can just save separately for every button state if your num of buttons is constant. (chk1= true, chk2= false etc..)
But I would not recommend that solution because it is not adaptive to dinamic change of number of items.

Comment: "NameOfThingToSave" must be unique per item. 

And also in onBindViewHolder you are setting  holder.fav.setChecked(false); 

There should be something like  holder.fav.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean("NameOfThingToSave", true)); or even better to  load all data from shared prefs int alist of object before sending them to adapter and in adapter load status from object and on check status change just change object state and save new state to shared prefs

Comment: so i putted holder.fav.setChecked(sharedPrefs.getBoolean("NameOfThingToS‌​ave", true)); 
in onCreateViewHolder and when the click happens                 editor.putBoolean("NameOfThingToSave", false); or true
nothing changed

Comment: okay it is working but it not working with the position all yes or all no :S

Comment: Instead of hardcoded string "NameOfThingToS‌​‌​ave" put everywhere something like ("key"+position) and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You use `"com.example.xyle"` to read the preferences and `"com.example.xyz"` to save them. You have to use the same string on both cases.

**Update**

You should remove `holder.fav.setChecked(false);` from `onBindViewHolder` since you set it on `onCreateViewHolder`.

Comment: yea my bad i did change it but it is the same not working thanks thought

Comment: i did it but still the sharepreference not saving my checked

Comment: okay it is working but it not working with the position all yes or all no :S