# Toggle Button positions in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, togglebutton

I have toggle buttons inside recycler view i'm saving the boolean value in sharedpreference to recognize if the toggle button is  pressed or not on every restart of application now the problem is 
when i click on a 1 toggle button and close the application every toggle button get on same thing for off button there is no position connection between the toggle button and recycler view here is my code

```
 @Override
public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.model,null);

    MyHolder holder=new MyHolder(v);
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = c.getSharedPreferences("lol", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Boolean a = sharedPrefs.getBoolean("abc" , false);
    if(a) {
        holder.fav.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(c, R.drawable.star_light));
        holder.fav.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        holder.fav.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(c, R.drawable.star_off));
        holder.fav.setChecked(false);
    }
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.nameTxt.setText(players[position]);
    holder.posTxt.setText(positions[position]);
    holder.img.setImageResource(images[position]);
    holder.fav.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked) {
               holder.fav.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(c,R.drawable.star_light));
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = c.getSharedPreferences("lol", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putBoolean("abc", true);
            editor.commit();
            } else {
                holder.fav.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(c, R.drawable.star_off));
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = c.getSharedPreferences("lol", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putBoolean("abc", false);
                editor.commit();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Ok you are correct. But what's your question?

Comment: The logic you used is wrong. You are using only one SharedPreferences 'abc' value to all toggle buttons.So it's reflecting to all if one got effected.

Comment: @josef.adamcik when i click on one toggle button and restart the application all the buttons toggels like they are one

Comment: @A-N-V-E-S-H so what should i do ? i can't give for 50 button different sharedpreference and new boolean key and value

Comment: @Eazyz yes. That is a correct statement but not a question. Your code is written in a way it have to behave as you described. But there are already answers which are explaining that.

Comment: i didn't found any other answer or a way for sharedPreference get the boolean value when the button clicked

Comment: So for that where you place "abc" change it with some position like "abc"+position. So when you come again its return value as you enter

Comment: thank you it worked how did i forget to add position in  the key :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it worked thank you all this is the right answer

```
 @Override
public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.model,null);

    MyHolder holder=new MyHolder(v);

    return holder;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyHolder holder, final int position) {


    holder.nameTxt.setText(players[position]);
    holder.posTxt.setText(positions[position]);
    holder.img.setImageResource(images[position]);
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = c.getSharedPreferences("lol", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Boolean a = sharedPrefs.getBoolean("abc" + position, false);
    if (a){
        holder.fav.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(c, R.drawable.star_light));
        holder.fav.setChecked(true);

    }else {
        holder.fav.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(c, R.drawable.star_off));
        holder.fav.setChecked(false);

    }


    holder.fav.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked){
                holder.fav.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(c,R.drawable.star_light));
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = c.getSharedPreferences("lol", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putBoolean("abc" + position, true);
            editor.commit();
            }
            else{
                holder.fav.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(c, R.drawable.star_off));
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = c.getSharedPreferences("lol", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putBoolean("abc" + position, false);
                editor.commit();

            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is wrong.

You should only use the `onCreateViewHolder()` to inflate layout.

The binding operations should be in `onBindViewHolder()`. Use toggle operations in `onBindViewHolder()`

Comment: i tried to add same code inside the onBindeView but same result

Answer (score 0):

I done a quick edit. Please check in detail. I used `position` in `SharedPreferences`. So each `toggle button` value save in different key. This may work.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = c.getSharedPreferences("lol", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

@Override
public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.model,null);

    MyHolder holder=new MyHolder(v);

    return holder;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyHolder holder, final int position) {


    holder.nameTxt.setText(players[position]);
    holder.posTxt.setText(positions[position]);
    holder.img.setImageResource(images[position]);

    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = c.getSharedPreferences("lol", MODE_PRIVATE);
        Boolean a = sharedPrefs.getBoolean("abc"+position , false);
        if (a){
            holder.fav.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(c, R.drawable.star_light));
            holder.fav.setChecked(true);

        }else {
            holder.fav.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(c, R.drawable.star_off));
            holder.fav.setChecked(false);

        }

    holder.fav.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked){
                holder.fav.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(c,R.drawable.star_light));

            editor.putBoolean("abc"+position, true);
            editor.commit();
            }
            else{
                holder.fav.setBackgroundDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(c, R.drawable.star_off));

                editor.putBoolean("abc"+position, false);
                editor.commit();

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I Think you got the solution !